# When switch between tabs of TabNavigator all of the tabs is mounting

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Shows console after switching from the first tab to second:

[image]

When it occurs, state of the previous tab is not saving, and the transition to next tab is slow

My [route config](https://pastebin.com/JA7pKgNu)

```
const NestedStack1 = StackNavigator({
    Tab1Page1: { screen: Tab1Page1 },
},{
    navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: 'screen'
    }
});

const NestedStack2 = StackNavigator({
    Tab2Page1: { screen: Tab2Page1 },
},{
    navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: 'screen'
    }
});

const ProfileScreenStack = StackNavigator({
    ProfileScreen: { screen: ProfileScreen },
},{
    navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: 'screen'
    }
});

export default TabNavigator({
    Tab1: { screen: NestedStack1 },
    Tab2: { screen: NestedStack2 },
    Tab3: { screen: Tab3 },
    Tab4: { screen: Tab4 },
    ProfileScreen: { screen: ProfileScreenStack }
},{
    tabBarOptions: {
        showLabel: false,
        activeTintColor: c.BLACK
    }
});
```

How to fix the update of tabs? switching should be quickly with saving state

Comment: hi, I'm not getting the real problem there. Could you be a little more plain?

Comment: for example, i have a map when I moving on it saves coordinates to state, when i switch to another tab and go back, coordinates of the map will be initial and not my previous, on my one tab can be not only map coordinates, can be a lot more data which should savable

Comment: I guess you are using redux?

Comment: @EnriqueDev you are right, and you suggest me save coordinates, and some flags like dropdown or menu isOpened, to redux store?

Comment: it would be a good solution. If you store it in redux and connect the component when you change the state in redux it would trigger a re-render in your component. Should I write the answer with this?

Comment: @EnriqueDev save to store will help me, but I do not like save to store a data which refers only to one component, and transition to next tab is slow, if is no solution to stop rerendering all tabs, maybe it will be my solution

Comment: It's a little hard to see where there error is without knowing how is implemented. Could you add a snippet with the relevant data? Are the components unmounting when you switch tabs?

Comment: @EnriqueDev https://pastebin.com/vM7J2vGu

Comment: I mean the way you are implementing your state

Comment: @EnriqueDev https://pastebin.com/rRmkJCd7
look on region there saves coordinates

Comment: I don't get why you have two StackNavigator with a single screen but I guess is for further development. Just a question comes to my mind: as I can see, you whole components are mounting and unmounting every time you switch a tab. Is your navigator at the top level? is the top level connected to redux?

Comment: @EnriqueDev top level is StackNavigator from which redirects to Tab navigator if user authorized, yes, the top navigator is connected to redux

Comment: @EnriqueDev i have there two Stacknavigators because surely in those tabs can be nested routes, it only mock page, later there I will write real component

Comment: @EnriqueDev one moment very bad for me, when I go form 1 tab to 2, then 3,4, and 5 tabs are mounting, it is not necessary

Comment: Yep, something is weird there. The expected tab navigator behaviour is to mount once and remain mounted under the parent component is unmounted.